# What does "work me right" in "I set an explosion if you don't work me right" mean?

Tags: slang, lyrics, songs

It's a quote from the song "Bomb" by Isa.
Here is the rest of the lyrics: https://www.musixmatch.com/de/songtext/Isa-3/Bomb

Comment: Hi Julian Welcome to ELU--song lyrics are usually off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

While the phrase "*work me*" can sometimes have a sexual meaning, as in the song ["Work me slow"](https://genius.com/Xscape-work-me-slow-lyrics) by Xscape, in **this** case it simply means ***treat me right***.

The song uses an extended metaphor comparing a person to a bomb.  If you don't defuse a bomb the right way, it will explode in your face, just like the lyrics describe.

> Cause I'm a bomb, bomb, on a bomb, bomb
>
> ...
>
> If you cut the wrong wire
>
> I set off tonight
>
> I set an explosion if you don't work me right

The lyrics are basically saying if you don't act carefully around me or *treat me right*, I'll blow up like an explosive device that's not handled properly.

Comment: Did you mean explode in your *face*?